# Missing Action Bar in Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) Emulator under Windows 7

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-3.0-honeycomb

The title pretty much says it all: I finally got my Lenovo Win7 machine updated to have the tools, platform tools and SDK support to build for Honeycomb, yet when I launch the emulator, I see no Action Bar.

Oh, and I did double check: I do have `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>`
(redundant, I know) in AndroidManifest.xml.

Reading http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html leaves me thinking that should be enough, it should show up even for a simple "Hello, World" app. Yet it does not. For that matter, neither do any other buttons: all I have is a huge screen with a gradient display of hexagonal tiling of the plane (obviously meant to look like a honeycomb), a Google search widget, a button for 'Apps', and a '+' sign (I am assuming the six tiny rectangles ar epart of the Apps button, but maybe they are for changing home screen? Maybe that IS the appearance of the Action Bar for the home screen app?)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the home screen. That is not your application. The home screen does not have an action bar, at least not of the same style as you get in regular apps.